# Can I load a local html file with the cheerio package in node.js?

Tags: jquery, html, node.js, local, cheerio

I have a few html files on my harddrive that I'd like to use jquery on to extract data from.  Is this possible to do using cheerio?  I've tried giving cheerio the local path but it doesn't work.  One idea I had would be to create a web server in node, read from the html file, and then pipe it to cheerio through the server - would this

Answer (score 74, accepted):

The input is an html string, so you need to read the html content yourself:

```
var fs = require('fs');

cheerio.load(fs.readFileSync('path/to/file.html'));
```

Comment: This should be added in documentation

Comment: how do i make this work from a relative path in my project directory? this didn't work for me.

Answer (score 11):

A html file can be read **asynchronously** with the `readFile` function from the `fs` module. When the reading of the file finished the callback function is passed two arguments `(err, data)`.

The received `data` contains the html content and can be simply passed to the cheerio `load` function.

```
var cheerio = require('cheerio');
var fs = require('fs'); 

fs.readFile('path/to/file.html', 'utf8', function(err, data) {

    if (err) throw err;

    var $ = cheerio.load(data);
    console.log($.html());
});
```

*Sidenote: Because the encoding utf8 is specified as an optional second argument, the `typeof` data is a string. If the encoding is ommitted data will be a [buffer](https://nodejs.org/api/buffer.html). The load function understands this nonetheless, because the buffer is internally converted to a string with:*

```
if (Buffer.isBuffer(content))
  content = content.toString();
```

Documentation of **[fs.readFile()](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_readfile_path_options_callback)**

Answer (score 3):

Extending `damphat`'s answer to make it work for relative paths:

```
import fs from 'fs';
import path from 'path';

const filePath = path.join(__dirname, './path/to/file.html');
const $ = cheerio.load(fs.readFileSync(filePath));
```