# How load several HTML files as "document" and then manipulate them with Javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, node.js

I want to create and manipulate several HTML files with `JavaScript` and `NodeJS`. The usual way to update HTML files is to include an update script at the top, but I want to create multiple HTML files with one JS file. I have a list with the necessary data to process. It contains the names for the HTML files and the data to put in.

My idea was to use a model.html file, which contains the data, that will be included in all of the files. This model file will be copied and renamed to the necessary file. Then I want to load it with a `NodeJS` module or any other way fit, so it will be recognized as `"document"` as if the script was included in the file. Then I want to manipulate it with plain JS. A for loop should iterate through the list and create the file, load it as "document", manipulate it and then go to the next file.

Is this possible?

Comment: https://cheerio.js.org/ if you want to play with just html, else you need to use a headless browser

Comment: `Is this possible?` Yes!!!

Comment: Can I also do something like cheerio.load('./model_file.html');  ? 

Oh yes I can https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20664841/can-i-load-a-local-html-file-with-the-cheerio-package-in-node-js

Comment: @karthikdivi Thank you! Cheerio looks like a really simple and easy to use solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to just parse the HTML and get the document and operate on it you can check https://cheerio.js.org/

If you want to execute the Javascript also then you need to use Headless browsers like Headless Chrome